# Connect to cPanel through SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to connect to cPanel through SSH. I am using Linux Mint Terminal in this regard. I am following [this](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/security/ssh-access/) tutorial.

[image]

```
user@workstation:~$ ssh -p 22 user@192.0.2.0
user@192.0.2.0's password:   // Which password should I use here ?
Last login: Wed Dec  9 08:31:49 2020 from 192.0.3.33
[user@server.example.com ~]#
```

Which password should I use here ?

Could anyone guide me step by step in this regard ?

Comment: “Which password should I use here?” - the password for “user” to whatever machine is 192.0.2.0, it appears it’s a blank password, since you immediately login. Did you configure the server yourself?

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. No, I didn't configure the server.

Comment: As I point out, it appears the password for that user is a blank password, since, a prompt is provided and authentication immediately happens. The administrator on the box could  confirm that theory.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. I'll knock to the administrator.